# Use contraction mapping theorem to prove

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Help! I am taking a math course, and I just can't figure out this proof:

Let $\alpha,\beta\in R^n$, $a\in R$, and $A$ be an $n\times n$ nonsingular matrix. Use contraction mapping theorem to prove that for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, the equation
$$
\alpha-Ax+\epsilon(a-\beta^\text{T}x)x=0
$$
has unique solution in
$$
D=\{x\in R^n: \Vert x-A^{-1}\alpha\Vert\leq 1\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing $a$ and $b$ instead of your $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and $\mu$ instead of your $a$.

The equation to be solved for $x$ can then be written as
$$Ax=a+\epsilon(\mu-b\cdot x)\>x\ .$$ Apply $A^{-1}$ on both sides to get
$$x=A^{-1}a +\epsilon(\mu-b\cdot x)\>A^{-1}x\ .$$
We now put $x:=A^{-1}a+y$ and obtain the following equation for the new unknown $y\>$:
$$y=\epsilon\bigl(\mu-b\cdot(A^{-1}a+y)\bigr)\ A^{-1}\bigl(A^{-1}a + y)=:T(y)\ .\tag{1}$$
We have to show that for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the equation $(1)$ has a unique solution $y\in B$, where $B:=\{y\in{\mathbb R}^n\>|\>|y|\leq1\}$.

Let $\|A^{-1}\|=:\rho$. Then for all $y\in B$ one has
$$|T(y)|\leq\epsilon\bigl(|\mu|+|b|(\rho|a|+1)\bigr)\rho(\rho|a|+1)\ .$$
Here the right side is $\leq1$ if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small. Therefore we have $T:\>B\to B$ for such $\epsilon$.

We now have to deal with $T(y)-T(y')$ for given points $y$, $y'\in B$. Here we make use of the bilinear structure of the expression $T(y)$. When
$$q(y)=(a-by)(c+dy)$$
then
$$\eqalign{q(y)-q(y')&=(a-by)(c+dy)-(a-by')(c+dy')\cr 
&=b(y'-y)(c+dy')+(a-by)d(y-y')\ .\cr}$$
By analogy we have
$$T(y)-T(y')=\epsilon\bigl(b\cdot(y'-y)\bigr)\ A^{-1}\bigl(A^{-1}a + y')+\epsilon\bigl(\mu-b\cdot(A^{-1}a+y)\bigr)\ A^{-1}(y-y')\ .$$
It follows that one has an estimate of the form
$$|T(y)-T(y')|\leq\epsilon\>C\>|y-y'|$$
with a suitable constant $C>0$. When $\epsilon<{1\over C}$ the mapping $T$ is contracting on $B$.

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand how $T(y)-T(y')$ equals to the right hand side in the next-to-last equation. I can not compute it to this form. Can you show me?

Comment: @Chen: See the update. A $y$ and a $y'$ got mixed up. It should be okay now.